# Using PHP/MySQL to replace multiple strings from a table

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a table called `Products` that contains Titles of products.  Some of these Titles have words I would like to replace. The table contains over 6,000 records.  The text strings are found in the `Title` Column

```
ID | Title | Description | Price
```

I have another table called `ReplaceText` that contains a list of strings I am searching for and new text string. (e.g. small | tiny) This currently has 102 records.

```
ID | OldString | NewString
```

I would like to create a PHP/MySQL script to search the `Title` field in the `Products` table for matching words from the 'OldString`field in the`ReplaceText` table.

I have tried various methods but all can't crack the code.  Please help :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us these "various methods" you've tried and maybe someone could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following approach, using only SQL queries.

First, create a temporary table `ProductsTMP` containing only the rows `Products` with a new `Title`.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ProductsTMP AS
SELECT p.ID, r.NewString AS Title, p.Description, p.Price
FROM Products p INNER JOIN ReplaceText r ON p.Title = r.OldString;
```

Then, remove the old rows from the original `Products` table:

```
DELETE FROM Products
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM ProductsTMP);
```

Finally, add the updated rows from `ProductsTMP` to the original table `Products`, and remove the temporary table:

```
INSERT INTO Products (ID, Title, Description, Price)
SELECT ID, Title, Description, Price FROM ProductsTMP;    
DROP TABLE ProductsTMP;
```